# matplotlib updating multiple subplots with set_xlim() speed issue

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, scroll

I'm tryining to implement scrolling function in matplotlib for 1D time series. I have ~20 datasets and I want to plot them all together in one figure like this:

```
current_position = int(0)
step = int(50)

N = len(array)
fig = plt.figure()

for i in range(0, N):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(N, 1, i + 1)
    ax.plot(array[i], 'k')
    ax.set_xlim(0,50)


plt.tight_layout()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', scroll)

plt.show()
```

I want to scroll through all sublopts at the same time whenever I click mouse button, therefore I set xlim on all axes whenever I click button

```
def scroll(event):

    global current_position
    global scroll

    current_position = current_position + step

    for axis in event.canvas.figure.axes:
            axis.set_xlim(current_position, current_position + step)

    fig.canvas.draw()
```

This works fine for few subplots and small samples, however when length of time series exceeds 100 000 points and there are more than 5 subplots scrolling becomes painfully slow.

Can I update my code somehow to efficiently handle large datasets or do I need another approach? Or maybe this is the limitations of matplotlib?

Comment: i would have thought that plotting more than half a million points is going the be slow however you want to set the axis limits.

Comment: I've tried to plot different range every-time instead of setting xlims, however that is even slower.

Comment: It is rather inefficient to plot points which nobody can see because they are outside the visible range. So instead of plotting all half a million points, you probably want to plot only those in the current axis range.

Comment: Yes, it is an option, however in that case I need to store all data in array and replot all subplots in a loop every time I click button and that works even slower (maybe bad code issue).

Comment: Your data is stored in an array anyways, you don't need to store it again. And you are redrawing the complete canvas anyways. The only difference is that instead of 0.5 Million points you would only draw a little fraction of it. That is for sure faster.